# What's the figurative meaning of "the end of the line"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, figurative

Leaving aside the strong sexual connotations of the [lyrics](http://www.lyricsdepot.com/pulp/this-is-hardcore.html) of Pulp's song "This Is Hardcore", I was wondering what is the figurative meaning of the expression the author used:

> "This is the end of the line"

I thought it could be "this is it" or also could mean "I am putting an end to this", but I am not sure.

I was curious about the possible uses of the phrase, not only this particular case (ie, this lyrics).

Also, I would like to know about the literal meaning.  Is it refering to a drawn line? A spoken line?

Comment: See also: [Traveling Wilburys](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwqhdRs4jyA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of the song, it seems to mean something like "it doesn't get better than this." That's not typically what the expression means.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/end_of_the_line) has these definitions:

1. The termination point of a railway or similar transportation system.
2. (idiomatic) Final cessation or discontinuance of a process, institution, or person, especially one which has existed for a considerable period of time; death.

You would typically use it to mean that whatever you're engaged in is over, has run its course, there's nowhere else for it to go. [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/end+of+the+line?s=t) gives the examples of a presidency term (s/he could never get re-elected) or a TV serial (declining viewership, it's time to stop the show).

Comment: It could also mean that the singer can stop looking for love now, he's found it.

Answer (score 3):

It referred to a railroad line originally, the last stop being the "end of the line".

Comment: On [Caltrain|http://www.caltrain.com/] the other day, I finally got a joke that puzzled me as a child in Colorado:  A passenger on a west-bound train asks the conductor, "Do we stop in San Francisco?"  The conductor answers, "If we don't, there'll be a *big splash*."